# Can SweetAlert2 be used on a browser pdf viewer via chrome extension?

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

I wonder if I can use sweetalert2 via chrome extension on a pdf viewer page on chrome extension. It doesn't seem to work. It works on non-pdf websites.
for example,
https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5257e.pdf

If it should be able to work, could you please explain how to do it? thanks